# Powershell enum parameter does not prevent multiple parameters being passed

Tags: powershell, enums, parameter-passing

I was under the assumption that an enum parameter would by default only take one parameter and would throw an exception when trying to pass two or more parameters.

```
enum Test {one; two; three}

function Test-Enum {[CmdletBinding()] param (
[Test]$number
) $number}
```

###### This works as expected

```
Test-Enum -number one
Test-Enum -number two
Test-Enum -number three
```

###### I would have expected an exception trying to pass two parameters

```
Test-Enum -number one, two     # outputs two
Test-Enum -number two, one     # outputs two
Test-Enum -number one, three   # outputs three
test-Enum -number three, one   # outputs three
```

###### These do trigger an exception

```
Test-Enum -number two, three   # Cannot convert value error
Test-Enum -number three, two   # Cannot convert value error
```

I'm missing something obvious here but I can't figure it out. How do I prevent calls to Test-Enum with more than one parameter?

```
PS F:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                            
----                           -----                                                            
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2673                                                   
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                          
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                          
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2673                                                  
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                  
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                              
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                              
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Up to at least PowerShell 7.3.4 (current as of this writing), PowerShell's parameter binder treats [`[enum]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Enum)-derived types that do *not* have the [`[Flags]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.FlagsAttribute) attribute (which makes them *bit fields* whose values can be *combined*) as if they did.
- This makes it invariably accept *multiple* values, which isn't appropriate for *non*-`[Flags]` enumeration types.

  - See [GitHub issue #19513](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19513) for a discussion of this problematic behavior.

---

Unfortunately, the PowerShell parameter binder allows you to pass *multiple* values to an `[enum]`-typed parameter *even if the specific type is *not* a `[Flags]`-decorated one* (in which case accepting *multiple* values is helpful and appropriate).

If multiple values are given, they are *bit-ORed*, and if the resulting number doesn't correspond to a defined value, an error occurs.

---

You can cast from *strings* to get equivalent behavior to understand what the parameter binder does (the numeric values of your enumeration values are implicitly `0` for `one`, `1` for `two` and `2` for `three`):

```bash
# -> Same as: [Test] (0 -bor 1) -> two
[Test] 'one, two'  

# -> Same as [Test] (1 -bor 2), which FAILS, because 1 -bor 2 is 3, 
#    and 3 isn't a defined value.
[Test] 'two, three'
```

While this behavior is appropriate and helpful for `[Flags]`-based enumeration types, it is *not* for those that aren't.

---

**Workaround for *Windows PowerShell***:

The workaround is cumbersome:

- Type your parameter as `[string]`, which automatically prevent passing *multiple* values.
- Use a `[ValidateScript({ … })]` attribute to verify that the string passed is the name of a value in enumeration `[Test]`.
- So as to also support tab-completion, add an `[ArgumentCompleter()]` attribute:

```bash
enum Test { one; two; three }

function Test-Enum {
  [CmdletBinding()] param (
    [ValidateScript({ 
        if ($_ -as [Test] -ne $null) { return $true } 
        throw "$_ is not a valid value. Try one of: $([enum]::GetNames([Test]))" 
      })]
    [ArgumentCompleter({ 
        param($unused1, $unused2, $wordToComplete) 
        [enum]::GetNames([Test]) -like "$wordToComplete*" 
      })]
    [string] $number
  ) 
  # Now it is safe to convert the [string] value to [Test]
  $enumVal = [Test] $number
  $enumVal
}
```

**Alternative**:

- If use of an `[enum]`-derived type isn't a must, you could use a [`[ValidateSet()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute) attribute and enumerate the acceptable values *as strings* in there.
  However, that doesn't give you type safety when working with the parameter value later.

---

**Workaround for [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**:

Use an auxiliary [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) that implements the [`System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator) interface interface, which you can use with `[ValidateSet()]` too, and inside of which you can use `[enum]::GetNames([Test])` to generated the valid names:

```bash
# PS v7+ only

enum Test {one; two; three}

# Helper class that implements IValidateSetValuesGenerator
# and returns the valid enumeration values, to be used with [ValidateSet] below.
class ValidTestEnumNames : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator { 
  [string[]] GetValidValues() { 
    return [enum]::GetNames([Test])
  }
}

function Test-Enum {
  [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
    [ValidateSet([ValidTestEnumNames])] # Use the class defined above.
    [string] $number
  ) 
  $enumVal = [Test] $number
  $enumVal
}
```